# How do i pull latest data from yahoo api?

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I am trying to pull the Latest data from Yahoo API but i am not sure how to.....

In the YQL page

```
  select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("USDJPY")
```

What would i add at the end to pull the latest result?

I tried `select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("USDJPY") ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1`

But it doesnt work

Because at the moment, the time of the result is totally random.

Thanks for your time

Comment: what is the result ?

Comment: Sometime its 10pm, then the next query is 1am, and 13.45am....totally random

Comment: why dont you use some where clause ?

Comment: I tried ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1, but the time is still totally random